# What does 'dashing in his black suit' mean in this sentence from the book the Kite Runner?

Tags: meaning

In the chapter two, paragraph seven, the sentence reads that

> There was a picture of my parents' wedding night, Baba **dashing** in his black suit and my mother a smiling young princess in white.

Comment: Did you look in any dictionaries where you could have found that 'dashing' can be an adjective meaning 'stylish and fashionable'?

Comment: I looked up the meaning of its verb and noun, but cannot find the meaning, never thought it was an adjective, but I know when you say dashing, as an adjective. thx

Comment: Check other *-ing* forms used adjectivally of people, such as ***charming, fetching, captivating, endearing, interesting, enchanting.*** You can't always figure out the adjectival meaning from the underlying verb, though (Lord knows how ***fetching*** came about! :) I think ***dashing*** is best understood by reference to ***cut a dash***, where the noun ***dash*** refers to ***[a mixture of] [stylishness, enthusiasm, and courage](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dash)***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "dashing" here actually is not the participle dash+ing, but an adjective meaning 'stylish and fashionable', or "attractive in a confident, exciting and stylish way" (Cambridge Dictionary).

Comment: Or "attractive in a confident, exciting and stylish way" (Cambridge Dictionary).